# Declare Gradle buildSrc plugin using Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this configuration to the Kotlin DSL, but I can't find much in the way of examples:

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        javaConventionsPlugin {
            id = "build.java-conventions"
            implementationClass = "buildlogic.plugins.JavaConventionsPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

What would this declaration look like using Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented in the guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#sec:gradle_plugin_dev_usage

The way you have also works. Any of the following would also work:

```
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("javaConventionsPlugin") {
            id = "build.java-conventions"
            implementationClass = "buildlogic.plugins.JavaConventionsPlugin"
        }
    }
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("javaConventionsPlugin") {
            id = "build.java-conventions"
            implementationClass = "buildlogic.plugins.JavaConventionsPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

The former uses Gradle's [lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html).

Comment: Thank you, all my searches kept bringing me to the [custom plugins page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html). I completely spaced on there being a separate plugin development plugin.

Comment: It is there as well, under [A standalone project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) section, switch to Kotlin using the tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found so far, not sure if there's a more fluent way to do it:

```kotlin
gradlePlugin {
    val javaConventionsPlugion = plugins.register("javaConventionsPlugin")
    javaConventionsPlugion.configure {
        id = "build.java-conventions"
        implementationClass = "buildlogic.plugins.JavaConventionsPlugin"
    }
}
```